# iPhone UIImageView not showing in set size

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimageview

I have a simple app, straight out of the SDK TabBar template, where I implemented UIImageView outlet set in the AppDelegate UIWindow. I want to display there a static image each time user taps a tabbar item. It works fine (the image is displayed and hidden when it should) with one exception:

I have created the UIImageView in IB and set the size 320x430, so the image does not hide the tabbar. The problem is, UIImageView always shows the size of the window, covering entire screen. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you set clipsToBounds to YES.